# Unused args [...] for include of [...]- Error launching ROS file

Tags: python, xml, ros, launch

I'm trying to pass an argument to a launch file and I keep getting the error. The main launch file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <arg name="logging" default="screen" />
  <arg name="ship_velocity" default="0.1" /> <!-- velocity between 0 and 5 m/s -->
  <arg name="ship_waypoints" default="[[2,6],[2,-4],[-2,-2],[4,-2],[-5,5],[4,4],[-6,-6]]" />
  <!-- <arg name="ship_waypoints" default="[[[8, 0], [6, 0], [4, 0] ,[2, 0] ,[0, 0], [2, 0], [4, 0], [6, 0], [8, 0]]]" /> -->
  <!-- Global as it is used by both ship_following_controller_node and ship_node -->
  <arg name="followed_epsilon" default="2.0"/>

  <include file="$(find flightgoggles)/launch/core.launch">
  </include>

  <include file="$(find visualizer)/launch/view.launch">
  </include>

  <include file="$(find flightcontroller)/launch/angle.launch">
  </include>

  <include file="$(find sensor_simulation)/launch/sensors.launch">
    <arg name="logging" default="$(arg logging)" />
    <arg name="ship_waypoints" default="$(arg ship_waypoints)" />
    <arg name="ship_velocity" default="$(arg ship_velocity)" />
    <arg name="followed_epsilon" default="$(arg followed_epsilon)" />
  </include>

  <node pkg="flightcontroller" type="attitude_thrust_controller.py" name="attitude_thrust_controller_node" output="screen">
  </node>

  <node pkg="simple_control" type="ship_following_controller.py" name="ship_following_controller_node" output="screen">
  <arg name="rate"/>
  <arg name="iz"/>
  <arg name="dz"/>
  <arg name="pz"/>
  <arg name="ixy"/>
  <arg name="dxy"/>
  <arg name="pxy"/>
  
  <param name="rate" type="int" value="$(arg rate)" />
  <param name="pxy" type="double" value="$(arg rate)" />
  <param name="pz" type="double" value="$(arg rate)" />
  <param name="dxy" type="double" value="$(arg rate)" />
  <param name="dz" type="double" value="$(arg rate)" />
  <param name="iz" type="double" value="$(arg rate)" />
  <param name="ixy" type="double" value="$(arg rate)" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

The included file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <include file="$(find flightcontroller)/launch/fly.launch">
    <arg name="ship_velocity" default="0.1" />
    <arg name="ship_waypoints" default="[[0, 0]]" />
    <arg name="rate" default="10" />
    <arg name="pxy" default="0.01" />
    <arg name="pz" default="0.5" />
    <arg name="dxy" default="1" />
    <arg name="dz" default="30" />
    <arg name="iz" default=".05" />
    <arg name="ixy" default="0.05" />

    <arg name="logging" default="log" />
  </include>

  <node name="debug_print_node" pkg="system_tests" type="print_node.py" output="screen"/>

  <test test-name="test_hovering" pkg="system_tests" type="drone_behavior_test.py" time-limit="120.0">
    <param name="duration" type="double" value="30.0" />
  </test>

</launch>
```

Yet I keep getting this error:

```
unused args [pxy, iz, dxy, pz, rate, ixy, dz] for include of [/root/CS4501-Labs/lab6_ws/src/flightcontroller/launch/fly.launch]
```

What is going on?

I tried to add the parameters as arguments in the launch file, as seen in the following post about the same issue: https://answers.ros.org/question/239384/unused-args-for-include-of/
It didn't seem to work and any other solutions also don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be inside your main launch file.
In `<node pkg="simple_control" type="ship_following_controller.py" name="ship_following_controller_node" output="screen">` you have some strange `arg` elements

The `node` element doesn't support the `arg` element.
You can check it here
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node

Only these are supported for the `node` element.

```
<env>
<remap>
<rosparam>
<param>
```

I am not sure what is your intention but I think that include for `fly.launch` should be in your main launch file. And the second file should contain a definition for the node instead of including of launch.

Answer (score 0):

`<include>` takes only `<arg>`

```
<!-- parent.launch -->
<include file="child.launch">
  <arg name="my_arg" default="0"/>
</include>
```

`<node>` takes only `<param>`

```
<!-- child.launch -->
<arg name="my_arg" default="0"/>
<node pkg="" type="" name="">
  <param name="my_arg" value="$(arg my_arg)"/>
</node>
```

Notice `<arg>` above `<node>` it's needed so you can pass arguments from parent launch file in `<include>`

---

In your specific case you put `<arg>` inside `<node>` which is not allowed `unused args [pxy, iz, dxy, pz, rate, ixy, dz]`

```
<node pkg="simple_control" type="ship_following_controller.py" name="ship_following_controller_node" output="screen">
  <arg name="rate"/>
  <arg name="iz"/>
  <arg name="dz"/>
  <arg name="pz"/>
  <arg name="ixy"/>
  <arg name="dxy"/>
  <arg name="pxy"/>
```